# ¿Qué quiere decir "tumbao"?

Tags: significado, modismos, colombia, música

Hay una canción de Celia Cruz: *La Negra Tiene Tumbao*.

¿Que quiere decir?

"Tumbao" por lo visto es un modo de caminar (segun [RAE](https://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=tumbao)), pero como se puede traducirla en inglés? Swagger?

¿O se trata de "[tumbado](https://www.significadode.org/tumbado.htm)"?

```
Dicho de determinadas cosas, como los baúles, los coches, etc.: De forma de tumba.
```

¿Baúles? ¿Quiere decir que la mujer tiene nalgas grandes o que camina con "swagger"?

¿Esta expresión se usa en Colombia también? ¿En toda America Latina?

¿Tiene una connotación exclusívamente femenina? ¿O puede un hombre tener tumbao?

Comment: There is also the song: **Bemba Colora** sung by her, too.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QXfRgOwqAYM Another intervocalic D is skipped! :)

Comment: And here is the GREAT and INCREDIBLE Cuban poet. Nicolás Guillén, with his own special use of colora for her pasa (so funny): http://www.los-poetas.com/c/guillen1.htm#MULATA

Comment: And the band: Azuquita y su **melao** [for melado]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsHtTUJZpIk&list=OLAK5uy_nGwPZv0QIZOcAQYgZMYf9PKEQDfW8iMpY&index=6

Answer (score 2):

Mira [aquí](https://www.habanacimarrona.com/p/gente.html) un ejemplo de "tumbao" que aclara que significa caminar de manera cadenciosa, con ritmo - muy probablemente viene de uno de los ritmos que se hacen con el instrumento [llamado](https://es.quora.com/Qu%C3%A9-significa-tener-tumbao?share=1) [tumba](https://www.escribircanciones.com.ar/instrumentos-musicales/tumba.html) (tumbadora). Yo diría que si podríamos decir que "swagger" se asemeja, si bien no es idéntico (si buscamos traducciones de la canción al inglés, algunas usan esa palabra.)

Según tu propio enlace "tumbao", entendido como una forma de caminar, es exclusivamente de Panamá y Cuba. En uno de los enlaces de arriba alguien indica que sí se usa en Venezuela. No sé si en Colombia se usa pero si sé que no es posible que en toda América Latina se use, porque donde yo nací no se utiliza :-)

Comment: Not sure whether this helps but in lyrics I found on-line it is spelled with a following aopstrophe, _tumbao'_

Comment: This is correct for the Spanish.  Many words in certain forms of spoken Spanish drop intervocalic d's or t's. For example: bailaora [Andalusia] for bailadora. Cuban and Caribbean music has a lot of this. I would not, however, say swagger. I would say a sexy way of walking. Generally, in English, men swagger, not women.

Comment: ¿Tiene una connotación femenina?

Comment: Women move their hips; their hips sway. swagger is to walk like a macho (machista).

Comment: En la canción 100% femenino - "la negra" - sin embargo hay un refrán que habla del tumbao que tienen los guapos al caminar, así que diría que funciona para cualquier persona

Answer (score 1):

Mainly on African-descendent slang is commonly used (Colombia) specially in the pacific area. I would say "swing" is the closest term to describe how the body shows an specific pattern and taste to the eyes matching the rhythm :)
References: Youtube: 'Cali Colombia (swing Latino) Youtube: "Los hermanos Rosario_La duena del swing"

Comment: African-descendent slang? That is not a correct definition. It would be: Afro-Colombian slang.

Comment: “The incorporation of the theme of Afro-descendants in international human rights law is relatively new. Only 18 years ago, the issue was raised at the Regional Conference of the Americas held in preparation for the Third World Conference against Racism, Racial Discrimination, Xenophobia and Related Intolerance in the city of Santiago, Chile in the year 2000.“ https://sur.conectas.org/en/afro-descendants-as-subjects-of-rights-in-international-human-rights-law/ the term you propose is also valid. There’s always something to complain.